# What is a good freeware MIDI editor for minor changes running on Windows?

Tags: composition, software, midi

I compose music on my CVP-501. I record the tracks on a MIDI (.mid) file and record them as a wave (.wav) file. However, being human, I make mistakes. Plus, my setup for recording could be a lot better.

A MIDI editor could fix both of these problems. I could fix the (minor) mistakes and export the file as audio. I realize that MIDI files save the notes and that audio files save the sound, but I have seen enough converters to know it's not impossible to convert between the two.

I am asking for good, free MIDI editors that will run on a Windows machine. I would like an audio conversion feature, but it's not a requirement (like I said, I've seen converters before).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need the source?  I've got a closed source one (windows) on http://pianocheetah.com (my personal site)

Comment: No, not really. I only need it to be free.

Comment: http://midieditor.sourceforge.net/ - not used it before though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MIDI_editors_and_sequencers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/home.php) works for window too, and is free for use.

Answer (score 1):

Try Anvil Studio, it's free and probably has all you need for basic editing, and more.